# asp.net impersonation setup

Tags: asp.net, impersonation

My web app is set to use Windows Authentication and Impersonation is set to true.

```
<authentication mode="Windows"/>
    <identity impersonate="true"/>
```

When I run it on my local machine (IIS6), I access Active directory with my current login.

```
WindowsIdentity curIdentity = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
WindowsPrincipal myPrincipal = new WindowsPrincipal(curIdentity);
```

However when I access my site remotely Impersonation does not seem to be working; I display the groups that the user belongs to - and get a very short list!

What else do I need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Impersonation does not pass credentials more than 1 hop between machines. So your creds go from your machine to IIS but no further, accessing active directory is a 2nd hop. When everything runs on the same machine (as in your local case), it will work fine.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa292118(VS.71).aspx

Comment: ...unless you are using Kerberos.

Comment: true it is more complex than this, you can start getting into account delegation and such to work around the limitation

Comment: OK, so just to confirm something... there is no way to get the (correct) username without using kerberos?

Comment: Right, worked out some important definitions:
1\ If you are using integrated security you are using Kerberos (this has been a confusing point, when people are refering to Kerberos they are usually talking about connecting to sql server)
2\ turn off anonymous access in IIS!!! - this solved my problem

Answer (score -1):

I'm pretty sure you need to be specifying a user:

```
<identity impersonate="true" userName="contoso\Jane" password="pass"/>
```

Otherwise it will use the ASP.Net user, which will have limited privileges.

See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xh507fc5%28VS.71%29.aspx) for more information (including how to store the username/password encrypted).